# What is the probability that server earns more than 500?

Tags: probability

A server ears tips with a mean of 8.9 and standard deviation of 4.5. If we assume that server gets 50 tips on the wekkends, find the probability that server earns 500 or more?

### thought

I think the problem is poorly written. If we call $X$ to be the amount of money during weekends he earns, Im trying to find $P(X > 500)$ . So, $\mu = 8.90 \times 50 = 445 $ and $\sigma =  4.5 \times 50 = 450$, then

$$ P(X > 500) = P(Z > 0.1222) $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you say $4.5 \times 500=450$?  It is $2250$

Comment: Z = 1.728483. Also depending on the distribution 50 obseravations may not be enough for the standard normal to be a good approximation, but broadly speaking this is the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is the number of tips the standard deviation of the sum scales with $\sqrt N$, so it is $4.5\sqrt{50}\approx 31.82$.  Then you need $Z\ge \frac{55}{4.5 \sqrt {50}}$

Comment: The variance increases linearly with $N$ and the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, so it increases with $\sqrt N$